# Disk with no primary partition mounted on disk-name itself

Tags: amazon-ec2, filesystems, partition, amazon-ebs, fdisk

I have a ec2-machine setup with an EBS attached of size 200 GB.
I obtain the following with the commands I perfomed
[Screnshot for the lsblk and df -hT commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKVyU.png)

As I could figure out from these, there seems to be no primary partition surprisingly and also the root is mounted onto **/dev/xvda** which in turn is the disk name.

Also this is the output for **fdisk**
[Screenshot for fdisk command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fVk2.png)

This also shows no partitions available. I also tried creating primary partition but then the instance didn't boot up and I have to make recovery using the EBS snapshot present, Please guide me on how to set things right, like creating a primary partition that will have the root mounted upon.

Kindly correct me if I'm lagging somewhere or if any additional information is required from my side.

Comment: What problem are you having? Your 200GB EBS volume is already mounted at /. Block devices are not required to have partitions in Linux.

Comment: @jordanm There existed a /dev/xvda1 earlier,
The size of this ebs volume was 2000 gb , for reducing that to 200G, I removed the files, made another disk of 200G, attached that to the instance, rsync the contents from the origninal /dev/xvda1 to new mounted system for that disk. Then I booted with this smaller disk at /dev/sda1. Then this all arrived.  I want to have that file-system back where /dev/xvda was disk and /dev/xvda1 was a primary partition having mounted on /

Comment: Why is it important that your root volume is partitioned?

Comment: @jordanm because I'm converting a MBR partition into GPT, and this state where a disk having no primary partition messes up in that process.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @jordanm Thats's not exactly a problem as defined in your link, Just wanted to know if its possible to make partition of that disk as they existed before, simple. Without affecting the system.